# How to post message to twitter and facebook using android app

Tags: android

I developed a social network application . i need After enter a text into edittext, i click the button(having 2 buttons) then it should be post to twitter or facebook based on user button click.

i'm getting all corresponding user AccessToken,OAuthToken and OAuthSecret from web services so i dont want to ask user for login credentials.

How can i achieve this,please provide me some suggestions.i'm completely new to this facebook and twitter so it will be good if explain step by step

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating Android apps, it is a frequent requirement to be able to post status updates on social networks like **Facebook**, Twitter and **LinkedIn**. The user experience is that users are first taken to a page where they can login to **Facebook**, **Twitter** or **LinkedIn**. Then the control returns back to the application which can now post messages on their behalf.

There are multiple ways of doing the integration. One is to use the SDKs available from **Facebook**, **Twitter** etc. which provide the API for sharing these. Second is to use open an embedded browser control and use **OAuth** for authentication and finally the REST APIs provided to post the update. Both of these are slightly tedious, since either you have to download and use the different APIs or you have to implement the complete protocol.

Fortunately there is an open source SDK available that is easy to use and allows integrating with several social networks. This is known as **SocialAuth Android SDK**. In addition to posting
status updates, you can also get user profile from **Facebook**, **Twitter** and **LinkedIn** using the API, which will allow you to register users as well.

Integrate Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, etc.. in Android go to this [How-to-integrate-Facebook-Twitter-Linkedin-in-Android](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/457153/How-to-integrate-Facebook-Twitter-Linkedin-in-Andr)

**Update:**
Try this with sharing :http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_twitter_integration.htm

**Update2:**

You must authenticate users with login credentials and let the user grant you access to your application so your application can post on his/her stream.

If the user hasn't authenticated to Tweeter yet, he'll be redirected via a browser
to the twitter login page. Once the user authenticated, he'll authorize the Android application to send
tweets on the users behalf.
And go to this [link](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-post-twitter-status-from-android/). Carefully read this steps

Comment: Thanks for reply, in that blog they are asking the credentials from the user,but for me i dont want to ask,how can i do that

Comment: ya i seen this i dont want to open any twitter or facebook dialogues, there user entering text on twitter compose i dont want like that

Comment: Hi it always showing pop up as connection failure,when ever i tried to  click twitter button